# Can you inject a value into a PHP object through assigning that value to it's reference

Tags: php, reference, tostring

Here's what I want to do:

```
$var = new ObjectICreated("yay");
echo $var; // outputs "yay" via the __toString() magic method
$var = "Boo"; // $var is still a ObjectICreated, but will now output "Boo" from __toString()
```

Am I crazy?  I think SimpleXML does this very thing, but I'm not sure how.  Any thoughts?

Reasoning: I want to track changes to a particular object without having to use billions of getters/setters.

Ok, thanks for the comments, for posterity.  SimpleXML DOES do this.  The following works based on code from http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php example #9.

```
$x = simplexml_load_string($xml); // xml from example #9
// Pre-reference value
print_r($x->movie[0]->characters->character[0]->name);  
// Assign to reference of a SimpleXMLElement
$x->movie[0]->characters->character[0]->name = 'Miss Coder';
print_r($x->movie[0]->characters->character[0]->name);
```

The output is as follows:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Ms Coder ) 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Miss Coder )
```

As you can see, it is still a SimpleXMLElement, as it was prior to the assignment of "Miss Coder".

Thank you again everyone for your time.

Comment: how to avoid billions of getters/setters, [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and `$var = "Boo"` will overwrite `$var` no matter what..

Comment: "I think SimpleXML does this very thing, but I'm not sure how" I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Comment: Directly from php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php
See example #9

Comment: That sets a property of the object. It doesn't change the instance and is something completely different from the example in your question. `$var = 'something'` <- sets the value of `$var` to something. `$var->property = 'something'` <- sets the value of a property of some object.

Comment: Might want to double check that.  It looks like they are assigning a string to a SimpleXMLElement object that then behaves like that object when the asXML() method is run on the top object of the chain.

Comment: *sigh* I don't double check anything when I know it doesn't work like that. They asign a string to a property period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all who responded.  I was able to come up with a solution that works for what I need.

Before I get there, as @PeeHaa stated, the __get and __set magic methods are the way to go here.  However, to reach the stated goal of the original post, we require an object hierarchy.  As far as I can tell, that's how SimpleXML is able to do what I described in my original post and subsequent edits, again alluded to by @PeeHaa in a comment.  My original idea is indeed impossible [deep sigh of regret].

Below is a very primitive view of what I'm going to do to accomplish this.  I've done some pre-work and it appears to work as expected.  Obviously, I am going to fill this out and refine it to fit my specific needs.  It is also missing some sub-object creation code and sub-type intelligence in the interest of brevity.

```
class Foo { 
    protected $_value;
    protected $children = array();
    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->_value = $value;
    }
    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->_value = $value;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->_value;
    }
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        if(isset($this->children[$key]) == false) {
            $this->children[$key] = new self($value);
        } else {
            $this->children[$key]->setValue($value);
        }
    }
    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->children[$key];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo("");
$foo->myVar = "some value"; // assigns "some value" to $foo->myValue->_value
print_r($foo->myVar); // outputs that we have a Foo
echo $foo->myVar; // outputs the contents of $foo->myValue->_value aka "some value"

// This works and produces the string value of both "myVar" and "anotherVar",
// with "anotherVar" being an instance of Foo.
$foo->myVar->anotherVar = "some other value";
```

Again, thank you all for your contributions and your patience as I worked this out.

Answer (score 2):

As @dbf says

> `$var = "Boo"` will overwrite $var no matter what

if you want to avoid getters/setters, you can simply expose a public member

```
$var = new ObjectICreated("yay");
echo $var; // outputs "yay" from $var->value via the __toString() magic method
$var->value = "Boo";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help me.  As I stated in my post I need to have some code that helps me track changes to the object.  A public property will not provide me with that ability.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent a lot of setters/getters you *could* implement magic setters / getters. Although often this is a code smell.

```
class Foo
{
    private $magicData = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->magicData[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->magicData[$name];
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do the following:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->something = 'bar';
$foo->reallyAnything = 'baz';

echo $foo->something;
```

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with these methods and have used them often.  However, this little snippet did inspire some creativity that allowed me to do what SimpleXML does, even if I couldn't do my original idea.  Thanks.